# Can ExifTool be used to read files stored online?

Tags: exiftool

I store some of my photos on a web server, and I'd like to be able to read the metadata with ExifTool.

Is it possible to use ExifTool to connect to files that are otherwise accessible online via common internet protocols, e.g., `http://`, `ftp://`, etc.?

For example, I tried the following command:

```
exiftool -all https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNrnd.jpg
```

It returned "file not found."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ExifTool has no built in ability to access online files. However, as shown in the example under [Piping Examples](https://sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/exiftool_pod.html#curl--s-http:-a.domain.com-bigfile.jpg-exiftool--fast), you can pipe the file from a program — such as cURL — to get the metadata of a file.

Comment: Yes, that example works! Using `curl -s https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNrnd.jpg | exiftool -fast -` returns 60+ tags.

Comment: Of course, it's worth being explicit that the entire file gets downloaded.

Comment: @osullic Will you elaborate?

Comment: @EJMak I just mean that cURL will download the file in its entirety, and then exiftool will do its analysis. It's just worth keeping in mind in case, perhaps, someone wants to do this as a batch operation on gigabytes of remote images. Some naive user might think that exiftool somehow just sniffs the metadata remotely, without downloading the full file to the local machine.

Comment: @osullic The `-fast` option in the exiftool example means that "ExifTool will not scan to the end of a JPEG image to check for an AFCP or PreviewImage trailer, or past the first comment in GIF images or the audio/video data in WAV/AVI files to search for additional metadata."  Once exiftool reaches that point, it will close the stream, which appears to shut down curl.  You can compare outputs by adding `-verbose` to the curl command and checking against a large file such as this [wikimedia file](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/ff/Pizigani_1367_Chart_10MB.jpg)